# a generator function that yields one result at a time

Tags: python

I wanna know why this generation function just get one result only

```
def scramble(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        seq = seq[1:] + seq[:1]
    yield seq

print(list(scramble('spam')))
```

returns `['spam']` instead of what I expected something like `['spam', 'pams', 'amsp', 'mspa']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please, put your code to the text field: someone would like to help you and try your code, but no one will retype it from a picture.

Comment: Thanks for your good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yield seq` line wasn't indented enough taking it out of the for loop.

```
def scramble(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        seq = seq[1:] + seq[:1]
        yield seq

print(list(scramble('spam')))
```